# How can I set 100% height on my Custom Google search iframe?

Tags: iframe, height, google-search, google-search-api

I am trying to make 100% height for custom google searh iFrame height. I am not able to control the height. When ever the result displays the iFrame height shows 1860. Below the results it shows big gap. But I want to make the height 100%. It should be automatically control the height depend on the results.

Please check below link
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/docs/ui.html#layout

Please let me know if anyone knows solution for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Place this under the adsense search code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try{document.getElementsByName('googleSearchFrame')[0].height=1100;}catch(e){}
</script>
```

Change the "height" to whatever you want.  This is a known problem with adsense custom search.  But the problem is, since google now shows images next to results, the box might be stretch and it gets cut off.